# Get Firebase Object data based on ID in another ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I have this broken [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/oWZEda?editors=0011) that I am attempting to get the info of an object in another Firebase Ref based on the objects `.key` or id...

I have to Firebase Refs: The content

```
[
  {
    "name": "objecta",
    ".key": "objecta"
  },
  {
    "name": "objectb",
    ".key": "objectb"
  },
  {
    "name": "objectc",
    ".key": "objectc"
  }
]
```

and the Related that lists the object by key and then the key of the ones that are related to that item.

```
[
  {
    "objectc": true,
    ".key": "objectb"
  }
]
```

I am trying to use the following code to go through the relatedRef by key:

```
var theKey = "objectb"

function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    relatedRef.child(key).on("child_added", snap => {
        let relateRef = relatedRef.child(snap.key);
        relateRef.once("value", cb);
        console.log('relate:' + relateRef)
    });
}
```

then get the data of the object that it's related to and log it to the console:

```
getDiscoverBarContent(theKey, snap => {
    var snapVal = snap.val();
    console.log(snapVal)
});
```

Currently it is returning null when I need it to return the object info in contentRef referenced in the relatedRef...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referencing the wrong ref in the JS function. Everything was right except this:

```
var theKey = "objectb"

function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
    relatedRef.child(key).on("child_added", snap => {
        //This should have referenced the contentRef:
        let relateRef = relatedRef.child(snap.key); 
        //like so
        let relateRef = contentRef.child(snap.key);
        relateRef.once("value", cb);
        console.log('relate:' + relateRef)
    });
}
```